# AOSP : how to switch/downgrade to froyo branch from master?

Tags: android, android-source

I downloaded the AOSP, but I forget to specify the froyo branch, so I got the master branch.
Because of this I got building error saying I need a 64bit system to build beyond Froyo (I managed to fix this by editing some makefiles, but I want to use Froyo specifically for sake of API level).

How can I switch to the froyo branch without re-downloading the whole AOSP? I tried `repo start froyo -all` and `repo checkout froyo` but I'm not sure, is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you shoud try this to get the froyo branch:

```
mkdir froyo 
cd froyo 
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b android-2.2.2_r1
repo sync
repo forall -c git checkout korg/froyo 
repo forall external/qemu sdk -c git checkout korg/tools_r6
```

Comment: Does not work. * [new tag]         v1.7.8.1   -> v1.7.8.1
 * [new tag]         v1.7.8.2   -> v1.7.8.2
Get git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)

android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
fatal: cannot obtain manifest git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git